# Automated Transcription navigation for Videos

Tags: user-research

To make the User Research a bit leaner i do not fully transcribe interviews but make notes (or a note taker does this). But sometimes i need to jump back to the interview video, just to see that exactly the user told about a specific topic.

My workflow is:

1. Extract automated transcript with pyTranscriber on my Mac. This gives out an srt file (transcript with time)
2. Using the srt file look at the time when the topic was discussed and manually go to the timepoint needed

The Step 2 is really cumbersome, and i want to know if someone knows a software that allows navigation in video through the srt?

Answer (score 0):

Found [Aegisub](https://aegisub.en.uptodown.com/windows). Works as intended, I even can rephrase the text.